# Unable to resolve the Azure Storage connection named 'Storage' - Azure durable functions

Tags: json, azure, azure-durable-functions

## My Project

### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "azure-functions",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "func start",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "durable-functions": "^2.0.2"
  }
}
```

### host.json

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  }
}
```

### DurableFunctionsHttpStart/function.json

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "route": "orchestrators/{functionName}",
      "methods": [
        "post",
        "get"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "name": "starter",
      "type": "orchestrationClient",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```

### DurableFunctionsHttpStart/index.js

```js
const df = require("durable-functions");

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    const client = df.getClient(context);
    const instanceId = await client.startNew(req.params.functionName, undefined, req.body);

    context.log(`Started orchestration with ID = '${instanceId}'.`);

    return client.createCheckStatusResponse(context.bindingData.req, instanceId);
};
```

### Hello/function.json

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "activityTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```

### Hello/index.js

```js
/*
 * This function is not intended to be invoked directly. Instead it will be
 * triggered by an orchestrator function.
 * 
 * Before running this sample, please:
 * - create a Durable orchestration function
 * - create a Durable HTTP starter function
 * - run 'npm install durable-functions' from the wwwroot folder of your
 *   function app in Kudu
 */

module.exports = async function (context) {
    return `Hello ${context.bindings.name}!`;
};
```

### HelloOrchestrator/function.json

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "context",
      "type": "orchestrationTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```

### HelloOrchestrator/index.js

```js
/*
 * This function is not intended to be invoked directly. Instead it will be
 * triggered by an HTTP starter function.
 * 
 * Before running this sample, please:
 * - create a Durable activity function (default name is "Hello")
 * - create a Durable HTTP starter function
 * - run 'npm install durable-functions' from the wwwroot folder of your 
 *    function app in Kudu
 */

const df = require("durable-functions");

module.exports = df.orchestrator(function* (context) {
    const outputs = [];

    // Replace "Hello" with the name of your Durable Activity Function.
    outputs.push(yield context.df.callActivity("Hello", "Tokyo"));
    outputs.push(yield context.df.callActivity("Hello", "Seattle"));
    outputs.push(yield context.df.callActivity("Hello", "London"));

    // returns ["Hello Tokyo!", "Hello Seattle!", "Hello London!"]
    return outputs;
});
```

Upon running `npm start` on the root of the page, i am getting the following error.

```js
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.4736 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.8.1.18957

[2022-09-05T11:52:51.483Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation '5dd1dd91-e64a-4866-......'.
[2022-09-05T11:52:51.483Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask: Unable to resolve the Azure Storage connection named 'Storage'.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')
```

What could be the reason, i followed this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-js-vscode

I didn’t get any prompt to select azure account as mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-js-vscode#test-the-function-locally

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That exception suggests that the runtime cannot find the value of `AzureWebJobsStorage`. You should have a `local.settings.json` file in your project that should look something like this:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=....",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node"
  }
}
```

The value of `AzureWebJobsStorage` should be set to a storage connection string that the Azure function runtime requires.

See: [App settings reference for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobsstorage)

Answer (score 2):

I got exactly the same error in a different scenario

- Durable functions
- Isolated mode
- .NET 7

In my case it turned out to be completely unrelated to anything mentioned here. I had a nested configuration element inside my local.settings.json, something like below:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "setting1": {
       "key1": "value1"
    }
  }
}
```

Turns out functions host doesn't like that, once I flattened the configuration structure the error went away.

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "setting1:key1": "value1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. it seems any invalid JSON causes this error. I had an extra {