# 504 gateway timeout azure durable function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am using this tutorial to create azure durable function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-js-vscode

> Note:- I am using premium plan

### host.json

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  },
  "functionTimeout": "00:40:00"
}
```

### Hello/index.js

```js
function delay(sec) {
  let now = Date.now();
  // run while loop for - sec
  while (now + sec * 1000 > Date.now());
}
module.exports = async function (context) {
  context.log("I am starting.");
  const startTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();

  // simulating a long-running task
  delay(5 * 60);
  const endTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
  return `${context.bindings.name} - ${startTime} -> ${endTime}`;
};
```

Sometimes call to the function `HelloOrchestrator` is working fine, but sometimes it responds with `504 gateway timeout`.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You did not share your whole code but it looks like you may be delaying a HTTP triggered function beyond 230 seconds which is the default idle timeout of Azure Load Balancer. That will lead to a 504 gateway timeout error.

From [Azure Function app timeout duration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#timeout):

> Regardless of the function app timeout setting, 230 seconds is the
> maximum amount of time that an HTTP triggered function can take to
> respond to a request. This is because of the default idle timeout of
> Azure Load Balancer.

Note that you should ideally only **schedule** an orchestrator in the HTTP trigger which normally takes some milliseconds and return an HTTP response. When the scheduled orchestrator runs, it can call an activity function which could be a long-running background task

Comment: Here is the whole code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73610382/unable-to-resolve-the-azure-storage-connection-named-storage-azure-durable-f

Comment: To avoid limit of 230 sec, we can use azure durable function. That’s what i am using.

Comment: Yes, I understand that so it suggests something is going wrong in your HTTPTrigger function. What is your Functions runtime version ?

Comment: The function runtime version is the latest, also I noticed that 504 gateway timeout issue is coming when we are trying to execute multiple functions simultaneously.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you are using `context.bindingData.req` in your HTTP Trigger instead of `context.req`. That was one of the breaking changes going from version 2.x to 3.x. [Breaking changes between 2.x and 3.x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=azure-cli%2Cin-process%2Cv4&pivots=programming-language-javascript#breaking-changes-between-2x-and-3x)